# Mount a webDAV to a specific disk

Tags: mount, fstab, 22.10, webdav, davfs2

I want to mount a webDAV to a specific disk. I am copying large files to the webDAV, but it appears when I do this, it takes up space on my main disk (which is not /media/username/Crucial) instead of the disk the webdav is mounted on. Can the `fstab` be setup to have files uploaded/downloaded/viewed (whatever triggers the file to be copied locally) to use the disk it is mounted on.

The relevant lines of my `/etc/fstab` are below:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<long-uuid> /media/username/Crucial auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
https://dav.box.com/dav /media/username/Crucial/box.com davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0
```

#### Version info

Ubuntu 22.10

```
mount.davfs -V
davfs2 1.6.1  <http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2>
```

#### Disk info

My main drive and secondary drive (Crucial) are ext4.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is involved?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `davfs2` configuration might be using a cache directory on your main disk that would cause it to consume space temporarily but with `WebDAV` the files you upload or download should use the disk space on the mounted disk.

Lets change the cache directory on your secondary drive, first we create the cache directory `mkdir /media/username/Crucial/davfs2_cache` then we open `davfs2` `sudo nano /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` we change the line that start with `cache_dir` like that `cache_dir /media/username/Crucial/davfs2_cache` then we save and exit the file and we unmount and mount `WebDAV`, now it should work

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I searched for the current cache directory and sure enough it was quite large. I'll be sure to implement your solution to put the cache on the desired drive.

Comment: You welcome :) dont forget to accept the answer if it fixed your problem.